# Question about DateTime in Data Frame vs DateTime in Google Big Query

Tags: python, dataframe, google-bigquery, bigdata

I'm trying to push data from a data frame to Google Big Query.

I set my date field of the data frame as

```
df['time'] = df['time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

and I set Google's Big Query date to `*DATETIME*`.  When I do the export from Python to GBQ, I get this error:

> InvalidSchema: Please verify that the structure and data types in the
>   DataFrame match the schema of the destination table.

If I make everything into string format, it works.  I don't think you can just set a data frame field to just `date`, right?  Is there a clever way to get this working, or do dates have to be set as strings?

TIA.

Comment: Could you print out the df['time'] and see if it matches [the format BQ needs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime-type)? You can even create a dateTime object of the same date and evaluate the two and see if they are considered equal.

Answer (score 1):

I found data loading with date and datetime type column is not working. So I tried with datatype timestamp and then could load the data in bigquery table.

while defining schema for date columns define it as timestamp as below.

```
bigquery.SchemaField('dateofbirth', 'timestamp')
```

and convert the dataframe column datatype from object to other datetime format which bigquery can understand.

```
df.dateofbirth=df.dateofbirth.astype('datetime64')
```

as of 8-mar-2019 date and datetime column type are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Changing datetime datatype to timestamp in biguery schema will give you a time value added with UTC. This might not be the ideal scenario for may of us. Rather try the below code:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=table_schema, source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
)
load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    dataframe, table_id, job_config=job_config
)
```